# issue while creating thumbnail in django

Tags: python, django

Code is like this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/big/')
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/small/')

    def create_thumbnail(self):        
        if not self.image:
            return         

        from PIL import Image
        from cStringIO import StringIO
        from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
        import os


        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (200,200)

        DJANGO_TYPE = self.image.file.content_type

        if DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/jpeg':
            PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'

        elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/png':
            PIL_TYPE = 'png'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'


        image = Image.open(StringIO(self.image.read()))


        image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)


        temp_handle = StringIO()
        image.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
        temp_handle.seek(0)


        suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.image.name)[-1],
         temp_handle.read(), content_type=DJANGO_TYPE)

        self.thumbnail.save('%s_thumbnail.%s'%(os.path.splitext(suf.name)[0],FILE_EXTENSION), suf, save=False)

        def save(self):         

           self.create_thumbnail()
           super(ImageWithThumbnail, self).save()
```

Now I want to save the thumbnail image in `documents/small/`. But how to call this `create_thumbnail` function from view or model when uploading the image to create the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

Did u mean you want to call the function in your views.
Then you can do

```
from urappname.models import Document
```

and call using

```
Document.create_thumbnail()
```

Comment: Actually i want to create the thumbnail on the fly while upload in the image .in my view page I am saving the data in database like this :            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'],thumbnail = request.FILES['docfile'])     
            newdoc.save()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overriding the default save() method of django.
For that, define this save() function under your model class as below:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.create_thumbnail()
    super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```